# Perl: how to split a file?

Tags: perl

I need to split a file into different ones.

Exmaple (original file):

```
*****3123123*****RAW
text1
text2
*****2312354***RAW
text3
```

Desired output:

[File1.txt]

```
*****3123123*****RAW    
text1
text2
```

[File2.txt]

```
*****312312354***RAW
text3
```

I tried to use split, but I always get some extra white characters into the array

```
open FILE, "<file";
@file= <FILE>;
close FILE;
@lines = split (/(RAW\n)/, "@file");
foreach $value (@lines) {
  if ($value =~ /[a-z]|[A-Z]|[1-9]/)  {
    print ("$value\n");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
*****3123123*****RAW

 text1
 text2

*****312312354***RAW

 text3
```

Edit: if I use print ("$value") instead of print ("$value\n") this is the output (notice the 1 extra space before the value:

```
*****3123123*****RAW
 text1
 text2

 *****12354***RAW
 text3
```

Comment: Isn't it just that when you're splitting, it's not removing the newlines, so when you add `print ("$value\n")`, you're adding an extra newline.  That's why it looks like there's extra whitespace.

Comment: without the \n I get 1 extra white space at the beginning of each value.

Comment: The extra space is because you're interpolating `@file` into a single string, which by default interposes a space character between the elements. It's usually better to read a file line by line unless it's really tiny, but if you insist on reading it all at once you could write `@lines = split (/(RAW\n)/, join '', @file` or slurp it all in at once with `my $data = do {local $/; <FILE>}; @lines = split (/(RAW\n)/, $data;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program pulls the decimal number from the `RAW` line and uses it to name the output files. It expects the input file name as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV or die "Input file required as command-line parameter\n";

my $out;

while (<>) {
  if ( /(\d+)\*+RAW$/ ) {
    open $out, '>', "$1.out" or die $!;
    select $out;
  }
  print $_ if $out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might do better with line-wise IO:

```perl
my $id = 0;
my $FILE = undef;

while (<>) {
    if (/RAW/) {
        close $FILE if defined $FILE;
        $id++;
        my $path = "File$id.txt";
        open $FILE, '>', $path or die "Could not open $path: $!";
    }
    print $FILE $_ if defined $FILE;
}
close $FILE if defined $FILE;
```

Copied and adapted from one of my scripts that splits a mailbox file into one file per mail. You will have to adapt the script if the first line does not match `/RAW/`

Comment: Tried to run your script but nothing happens. The script starts but never finish, so I have to Ctrl-C it.

Comment: @user1444482: this solution works fine. It expects the input file on the command line like mine does. If you don't supply one it will hang waiting for input from the keyboard.

Comment: I did not really think about it. To have others fix bugs in my code?

Answer (score 2):

```
use strictures;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);
my $raw = read_file('raw.txt', binmode => ':raw');
my $header = qr/^ (?= [*]+ [0-9]+ [*]+ RAW\n)/msx;
my @chunks = split $header, $raw;
# (
#     "*****3123123*****RAW\ntext1\ntext2\n",
#     "*****2312354***RAW\ntext3"
# )
for my $i (1..@chunks) {
    write_file("File$i.txt", {binmode => ':raw'}, $chunks[$i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Woah you definitely win the Perl golf heh

Comment: That's not even golf, that's straight-forward Perl how a seasoned programmer writes it. There is no obscure knowledge about it, only **remembering the capabilities of built-ins** such as [split](http://p3rl.org/split) and **using CPAN libraries** where appropriate.

Comment: Because I have to pick something sane, to safe-guard against copy-paste programming. I want my demo programs to be robust that way. I don't know the actual encoding of the file, but that's fine, `split` works with byte semantics, too. – Just imagine what would happen if I left the IO layer away! ☹

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. I can't help but feel this is reinventing the wheel.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
my $fi, $fi2;
my $line;
my $i;
my @lines;
my @filenameparts;
my $filename = "file_1.txt";

open($fi, "< original.txt");
@lines = <$fi>;
open ($fi2, " > $filename");

foreach (@lines)
{
if (($i > 0) and $_ =~ /RAW/)
{
    @filenameparts = split("_", $filename);
    foreach (@filenameparts)
    {
        print "Woooo".$_;
    }
    @filenameparts[1] = substr(@filenameparts[1], 0, @filenameparts[1].length() - 5);
    @filenameparts[1] = ($filenameparts[1] + 1);
    $filename = @filenameparts[0]."_".@filenameparts[1].".txt";
    print $filename;
    close($fi2);
    open ($fi2, " > $filename");
    $i = 0;
    print $fi2 $_;

}
else
{
    print $fi2 $_;
}
$i++;

}
```

Comment: You must get into the habit of adding `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your Perl programs. That would reveal a lot of problems with your programming that aren't otherwise apparent. You should also remember that you are programming Perl and not Java, JavaScript or C++ - wherever you have come from - as `@filenameparts[1].length()` doesn't get you the length of the second string in the array, it concatenates the second string with the length of `$_` which isn't at all the same thing.

Comment: I heartily agree with you that my Perl programming is poor.

Comment: Just trying to help you improve :) btw my solution is much golfier than daxim's :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with code you made, then simply just replace your line `print ("$value\n");` with `print ("$value");` and you've got it...

Or before `print` remove `\n` with `chomp($value);` and stay with output `print ("$value\n");`.