# How to generate two files from a single source in Perl?

Tags: perl

Here's a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948854/perl-how-to-split-a-file). I have this **Source File** and I want to put *Blue* records in **blue.out** and *Green* records in **green.out**. Where do I go from here?

```
Blue 1-3
a
b
Green 1-3
d
e
Blue 4-6
i
j
Blue 7-9
m
n
Green 4-6
p
q
Green 7-9
s
t
```

**Desired Output**  Two files **blue.out** and **green.out**

```
blue.out           green.out
------------------------------
a                  d   
b                  e   
i                  p
j                  q
m                  s
n                  t
```

Here's my code

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
my $blue = 'Blue';
my $green= 'Green';

while (<>) {
    if (/$blue/) {
        open(BLUEOUT,">>blue.out");
    print BLUEOUT $_ ;
}
    if (/$green/) {
        open(GREENOUT,">>green.out");
    print GREENOUT $_ ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
open my $blue,  ">", "blue.out"  or die "could not open output file blue.out: $?";
open my $green, ">", "green.out" or die "could not open output file green.out: $?";

my $curr = undef;

while (<>) 
{
    if (/Blue/)  { $curr = $blue;  next; }
    if (/Green/) { $curr = $green; next; }
    print $curr $_ if defined $curr;
}

close $blue;
close $green;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably best to open the files before the loop. It's also probably best to use lexical file handles.  You can then use the 'green' and 'blue' lines to switch between file handles, while skipping over that line, printing to the current file otherwise.

```
open my $green, '>', "green.out" or die;
open my $blue,  '>', "blue.out"  or die;

my $output;

while (<>)
{
    if (m/^Green/) { $output = $green; next; }
    if (m/^Blue/)  { $output = $blue;  next; }
    die "No colour specified yet" if !defined $output;
    print $output $_;  # NB: no comma!
}
```

*Warning: untested code!*

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $file, %fh );
while (<>) {
    if (/^([A-Z][a-z]+.+?)(?=\s+\d+-\d+$)/) {
        $file = lc $1;
        open $fh{$file}, '>', $file . '.out' or die
          if !exists $fh{$file};
    }
    else {
        print { $fh{$file} } $_;
    }
}
```

This captures the colors' names for the file names, and writes the letters below those colors to those files.  This avoids having to 'hard code' for the colors and file names.

Hope this helps!

Comment: For the sample data, performance is unlikely to be an issue, but repeatedly opening (and implicitly closing) the files is fairly expensive — a file open is an expensive system call. We can also quibble about ".txt" vs ".out" and file names with all lower-case vs mixed-case, but quibbling is the correct word.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Point well made. Fixed. I was primarily thinking of avoiding having to hard-code the colors' file-names.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : This bit of code I just whipped up might be overkill, but you can never have too much overkill:  http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/dl/hash_open.pl

Comment: @JoeZ: neat — nothing like a good bit of overkill every now and then! Kenosis, looks good.